# Is there a way in Salesforce to redirect a custom visulalforce page to a standard one?

Tags: custom-button, visualforce, redirect

I have created a custom button with associated custom visualforce page.

Every time the custom button is pressed it opens the custom visualforce page.

What I would like know is how to prevent the custom visualforce to appear every time the custom button is pressed?

Instead I would like to appear the previous standard page and to be able redirect the vf page to the standard one so when the custom button is pressed NO CUSTOM Visulalforce page TO APPEAR.

Is there a way in Salesforce to redirect a custom visulalforce page to a standard one?

Thank you

Comment: Provide details like where did custom button actually locate, to which page you need to redirect etc.

Comment: Well, you might think your question is already clear but it really isn't. In which circumstance do you want to standard sf page and which you want the VF page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i could understand your question,you are asking to display a standard page without going to a vf page on click of a button .

You can use action tag in apex:page and call the method to redirect to the standardpage from the action tag.

```
<apex:page controller="testcontroller" action="{!redirectToStandardPage}">
</apex:page>
```

As per the documentation:
The action method invoked when this page is requested by the server. Use expression language to reference an action method. For example, action="{!doAction}" references the doAction() method in the controller.

If an action isn’t specified, the page loads as usual. If the action method returns null, the page simply refreshes.

This method is called before the page is rendered, and allows you to optionally redirect the user to another page.

**Important:** This action should not be used for initialization or DML.